# Alignment difference when new questions are loaded on SO

Tags: support, bug

When I clicked on a `1 question with new activity` on an SO page, the new question was displayed, but with a visible misalignment from the rest of the questions. Is this intended? Please see the screenshot below.

[image]

**Browser** - 86.0.1 (64-bit)

**OS** - macOS Mojave 10.14.6